# Calling a macro from Excel ribbon control - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So, I have a macro, `LoadData`, that I want to call in two separate macros, `TransmitNewAndOldRecords` and `refresh`, which are in turn called from a button on a custom tab of the Excel ribbon.

The `TransmitNewAndOldRecords` works fine.  Here is the code for it.  You can see the call at the second to last line of the macro.

```
Sub TransmitNewAndOldRecords(control As IRibbonControl)
'Reference Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim pgconn As String
Dim Year As String
Dim SQLDelete As String
Dim SQLInsert As String

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

Year = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SQL Creator").Range("Year").Value

pgconn = "Driver={PostgreSQL};" & _
        "Server = me;" & _
        "Port = 1234;" & _
        "Database = database;" & _
        "Uid = me;" & _
        "Pwd = me;"

conn.ConnectionString = pgconn
conn.Open "PostgreSQL35W", "me", "me"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

'Tests if there are any records to delete.  If so, define SQLDelete variable and execute SQL string that is assigned to SQLDelete variable.
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("DELETE"), "Y") <> 0 Then
    SQLDelete = DeleteRecords(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Budget").Range("DELETE"), Year)
    cmd.CommandText = SQLDelete
    cmd.Execute
End If

'Tests if there are any records to insert.  If so, define SQLInsert variable and execute SQL string that is assgined to SQLInsert variable.
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("INSERT"), "Y") <> 0 Then
    SQLInsert = InsertRecords(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Budget").Range("INSERT"), Year)
    cmd.CommandText = SQLInsert
    cmd.Execute
End If


conn.Close

'If there are no new/old records to insert/delete, then display message box stating that.  IOF
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("DELETE"), "Y") = 0 And WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("INSERT"), "Y") = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No data to insert/delete into/from table.", vbOKOnly
Else
    MsgBox "Data saved successfully!", vbOKOnly
End If

Set conn = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing

Call LoadData

End Sub
```

I also call the `LoadData` macro in a very simple macro, `refresh` (seen below), that just calls `LoadData`. I get an error (Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment) when I run `refresh`.  However, if I add the "control as iRibbonControl" parameter to `LoadData`, it works just fine when called from `refresh`, but then I get an "Argument not optional" error in the `TransmitNewAndOldRecords` macro above when calling `LoadData`.

```
Sub refresh(control As IRibbonControl)

Call LoadData

End Sub
```

I'm really confused, because if I add the "control as IRibbonControl" parameter to `LoadData`, then the `refresh` macro works, but the `TransmitNewAndOldRecords` macro errors out.  But, if I don't add the "control as IRibbonControl" parameter to `LoadData`, then the `refresh` macro errors out and the TransmitNewAndOldRecords works.

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Here is the LoadData macro in case it's needed:

```
Sub LoadData()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim pgconn As String
Dim Team As Range
Dim FC As Range
Dim SQL As String

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set Team = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Info").Range("Info_Team")
Set FC = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Info").Range("Info_FundingCategory")
SQL = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SQL Creator").Range("BudgetSQL")

pgconn = "Driver={PostgreSQL};" & _
        "Server = me;" & _
        "Port = 1234;" & _
        "Database = database;" & _
        "Uid = me;" & _
        "Pwd = me;"

conn.ConnectionString = pgconn
conn.Open "PostgreSQL35W", "me", "me"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

cmd.CommandText = SQL

rs.Open cmd
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Budget").Range("A11:Y500").ClearContents
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Budget").Range("A11").CopyFromRecordset rs
rs.Close
conn.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you **sure** you didn't assign `LoadData` to the other button?

Comment: okay not really the answer to the Problem, but does it work with "Optional control As IRibbonControl" ? But i am with rory, sounds like you bound "LoadData" to the second button and not "refresh"

Comment: Arg!  You're right @Rory.  The XML for the button that I thought called the refresh macro actually calls the LoadData macro, so that explains the error.  Thanks!  I'm glad it's an easy fix.  Can you make you're comment an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer?  Thanks for your suggestion also Doktor Oswaldo - making the parameter optional would do the trick if I were to leave the XML as it currently is.  Thanks to you both.